# My 4 x 4 matrices aren't printing out C++

Tags: c++, matrix

So I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I know it's going to be something small and simple, but I do need just a little help on this please. It is only printing out the first numbers of each line for the most part, after that it just prints out 0's. It could just be that I've been staring at the computer all day and the stress is causing my brain to not function very well but any help would be awesome. I do know that most people use i's and j's but I like to use r's to represent the rows and c's for the columns.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int m1[4][4] = {(1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1)};
    int m2[4][4] = {(0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3)};
    int m3[4][4] = {(5, 8, 2, 5), (4, 7, 1, 4), (6, 9, 3, 6), (4, 5, 6, 4)};
    int m4[4][4] = {(1, 3, 7, 9), (2, 6, 8, 4), (7, 8, 9, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4)};

    //print matrix 1
    cout << "Matrix 1: " << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            cout << m1[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;


    //print natrix 2
    cout << "Matrix 2: " << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            cout << m2[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    //print matrix 3
    cout << "Matrix 3: " << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            cout << m3[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    //print matrix 4
    cout << "Matrix 4: " << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            cout << m4[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Probably because your code gives warnings about initialization: 
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Comment: I'm voting to close this as caused by a simple typographic error, because you simply used the wrong type of brackets, for no apparent reason, and got the unwanted result that the syntax rules clearly indicate would occur.

Comment: Also, if you saw that one matrix didn't print, why didn't you spend the time to create just one matrix, test it, and when you see it didn't work, post just that one matrix and one loop?  Posting 4 matrices and having to scroll through that entire code was not necessary.  That is what is meant by a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Use braces `{}` instead of parentheses `()`. With parentheses you simply have a  comma separated expression that evaluates to the right most number (thus initializing only the first row) and the remaining elements are [default initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) to `0`. What you want is called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Instead of:

```
int m1[4][4] = { (1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1) };
```

use:

```
int m1[4][4] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 4, 3, 2, 1 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 4, 3, 2, 1 } };
```

and repeat for the remaining matrices.